# Listen to changing network and detect internet available only work once

Tags: android

i wrote simple `BroadcastReceiver` to detect internet connection and check internet available to send data to server, only return true on first opening application, it mean, after open application this `BroadcastReceiver` can be detect correctly connecting to internet, after that on each turn on/turn off wifi i get only false and it doesn't correct and must be true or false

```
public class ConnectionListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context mContext, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("check ", isNetworkAvailable(mContext) + "");
        if (isNetworkAvailable(mContext)) {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new EventNetworkConnectionStateEvent(EventNetworkConnectionStateEvent.ConnectionState.connected));
        } else
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new EventNetworkConnectionStateEvent(EventNetworkConnectionStateEvent.ConnectionState.disconnected));
    }
}
```

manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

receiver:

```
<receiver android:name="..Broadcasts.ConnectionListener">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: activeNetworkInfo.isConnected() returns true only if its connected to internet and it is possible to pass data which means an active internet and not just a wifi connection. Are you sure the wifi connection you are trying to connect to and test has an active internet connection?

Comment: @kapsym yes i know it, and i'm sure, after each turn on/off i get only false

Comment: I use to check additional condition of activeNetworkInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED